# sifr3 - link not clickable when wmode set to transparent (Firefox)

Tags: hyperlink, hover, transparent, sifr3, wmode

```
sIFR.replace(cochin, {
    selector: 'h1',
    tuneHeight:-5,
    wmode: 'transparent'
          , css: [
            '.sIFR-root { text-align: left; font-weight: bold; color: #959595; line-height: 1em; leading: -2}'
            , 'a { text-decoration: none;}'
            , 'a:link { color: #959595; }'
            , 'a:hover { color: #bbbaba; }'
          ]
          , filters: {
              DropShadow: {
                  distance: 1
              , color: '#2d2a26'
              , strength: 1
              }
          }

});
```

If replaced element is link and if `wmode: 'transparent'` is set then I noticed following bug:
- if I scroll page, click somewhere (not on sifr link) and then go with mouse over a sifr link I don't have hand (point) cursor (default one is showed). If I click on a link then after mouse realase cursor changes to hand and then link get normal behaviour (hover is also active).
If I remove `wmode: 'transparent'` then link acts normally. This is noticed in Firefox, in IE it works normally.

Anyone had similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue with firefox. The only workaround I've found is to add this css rule :

```
.fontname:hover {background-position:0% 100%;}
```

In this example, fontname is the CSS class that determines which tags are replaced (in your case, that would be h1:hover)